# Count consecutive characters in a list?

Tags: scala, recursion

I want to create a scala method that counts the number of consecutive characters where the values are the same.  So I have this list:

List('a','a','b')

and I want to return something like List(('a', 2), 'b', 1) - because there two characters with the same values beside each other.  I've had a bash at this with little success:

```
  def recursivelyCompressList(list: List[(Char, Int)], newString: List[(Char, Int)]): List[(Char, Int)] = {

    list match {
      case Nil => newString
      case s :: tail => {
        if (tail.nonEmpty && s._1 == tail.head._1) {
          recursivelyCompressList(tail, newString :+ (s._1, s._2 + 1))
        } else {
          recursivelyCompressList(tail, newString :+ s)
        }

      }
      case _ => newString

    }

  }
```

Grateful for any guidance.

Comment: If there are two or more chains of repeating characters, do you only want the longest chain or all of them counted?

Answer (score 1):

This should work.
I would expect the code to be self-explaining, but if you have any question, do not doubt to ask.

```
def compressList[T](list: List[T]): List[(T, Int)] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[T], currentValue: T, currentCount: Int, acc: List[(T, Int)]): List[(T, Int)] =
    remaining match {
      case Nil =>
        ((currentValue -> currentCount) :: acc).reverse

      case t :: tail =>
        if (t == currentValue)
          loop(
            remaining = tail,
            currentValue,
            currentCount + 1,
            acc
          )
        else
          loop(
            remaining = tail,
            currentValue = t,
            currentCount = 1,
            (currentValue -> currentCount) :: acc
          )
    }

  list match {
    case Nil =>
      Nil

    case t :: tail =>
      loop(
        remaining = tail,
        currentValue = t,
        currentCount = 1,
        acc = List.empty
      )
  }
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
compressList(List.empty[Char])
// res: List[(Char, Int)] = List()

compressList(List('a', 'b'))
// res: List[(Char, Int)] = List(('a', 1), ('b', 1))

compressList(List('a', 'a', 'b'))
// res: List[(Char, Int)] = List(('a', 2), ('b', 1))

compressList(List('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c'))
// res: List[(Char, Int)] = List(('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('a', 1), ('c', 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

can also use `span` instead of dropWhile and takeWhile to avoid double scan

```scala
def comp(xs:List[Char]):List[(Char,Int)] =
    if(xs.isEmpty) Nil
    else {
      val h = xs.head
      val (m,r) = xs.span(_ == h)
      (h, m.length) :: comp(r)
    }
```

Comment: This is the coolest solution as it can easily be modified to cover both the case that only longest repeating sequences are needed vs the case that all repeating sequences are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `takeWhile` and `dropWhile`

Count consecutive

```
def count(xs: List[Char]): List[(Char, Int)] =
if (xs.isEmpty) Nil else
 (xs.head, xs.takeWhile(_ == xs.head).length) :: count(xs.dropWhile(_ == xs.head))
```

## Scala REPL

```
scala> def count(xs: List[Char]): List[(Char, Int)] =
     | if (xs.isEmpty) Nil else
     |  (xs.head, xs.takeWhile(_ == xs.head).length) :: count(xs.dropWhile(_ == xs.head))
count: (xs: List[Char])List[(Char, Int)]

scala> count(List('a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'))
res0: List[(Char, Int)] = List((a,2), (b,1), (c,3))

scala> count(List('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c'))
res1: List[(Char, Int)] = List((a,2), (b,1), (a,1), (c,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the behavior you want if there are multiple repeating sequences of the same character. Assuming you only want the longest repeating sequence, the following code would be a good starting point:

```
def rec(list : List[Char]) : Map[Char, Int] = {

  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def helper(prev: Char, li : List[Char], len : Int, result : Map[Char, Int]) : Map[Char,Int] = {
    if(li.isEmpty) {
      if(!result.contains(prev)) result + (prev -> len)
      else if(result(prev) < len) result + (prev -> len)
      else result
    }
    else {
      val cur = li.head
      if(cur != prev) {
        if(result.contains(prev)) {
          if(result(prev) < len)
            helper(li.head, li.tail, 1, result + (prev -> len))
          else
            helper(li.head, li.tail, 1, result)
        } else {
          helper(li.head, li.tail, 1, result + (prev -> len))
        }
      } else {
        helper(li.head, li.tail, len + 1, result)
      }
    }
  }
  helper('\0', list, 0, Map.empty[Char, Int]) - '\0'
}
```

Running

```
rec(List('c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'd' ,'c', 'c' , 'a', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd','c','c','a', 'c','c','c'))
```

Output:

```
res0: Map[Char,Int] = Map(c -> 3, a -> 3, d -> 4)
```

The idea is just to look at the current character in the list and the previous character. When the character changes, the sequence count is stopped and current length is compared to what is stored in the map. It's pretty simple when you come to think about it.

I think this can be written more elegantly. But it could be a good starting point.